# What can be an idiom for nepotism?

Tags: idiom-requests

In my native language, we use the word 'courgette' or 'zucchini' to mean something like nepotism in English. Its origin goes back to the days where there were walls around districts and merchants had to wait at the gates to enter their merchandise which was fruit and vegetables. Those who sold courgettes used to cry 'Courgette!' so they were allowed in first as this kind of vegetable goes bad fast in our hot climate.
Is there an idiomatic expression in English that is equivalent to 'courgette'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd use nepotism to describe your example of commercial 'preference'. In your example, the merchant's products determine if they have preference or not. In nepotism, it would be the merchant's familial relationship to the gate guards that would determine their preference. It's easier to change the products you sell than it is to change your family.

Comment: As abstract nouns, there is favouritism, nepotism and similar words and with various nuances, but they all literal. There may be other words but you would have to give context via an example of the conversation that would give rise to "Courgette!"

Comment: Your story relates to the vegetable sellers being given priority for a valid reason. Nepotism refers to people being given an unfair advantage because of family relationship to someone in high office.

Comment: More related to nepotism than vegetables: the [**old boy network**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/old+boy+network) and [**pull some strings**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+some+strings).

Comment: You're asking for help on translating an idiom from a language that few (if any) of us speak. You'll have to provide more guidance on context and background information on the sort of favouritism. (Things like Weather Vane's "old boy network" or similarly "old school tie" may or may not apply).

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying that gives  the same feeling of someone's claiming priority. It is often used humorously as parody rather than seriously. It is:

> "*Let me through, I'm a doctor!*"
>
> [Ola Lindberg](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2%3A512147/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

Ola's opening is worth quoting in full:

"*The scene is familiar. A crowd surrounds an injured person unsure what
to do until someone pushes his or her way to the unfortunate person
while shouting, “Let me through, I’m a doctor!” While the scene is probably recognized by most, if not all, it is harder to pinpoint a precise film
or TV series where it occurs. In my efforts to identify an example of this
scene, I finally ended up on a popular film and creative writing website
which classifies the scene as “seen it a million times”. This classification
is defined as a cliché, used and parodied so many times that people have
a hard time actually remembering where or when they have seen it.*"

And here is an example of the "*Let me through* ..." style of parody:

[Cartoon Stock](https://www.cartoonstock.com/directory/r/rubbernecking.asp)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heads up. Coming through, Watch out. [**Hot Soup!**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hot%20Soup)

> **Hot Soup** (Urban Dictionary #3):  When you're trying to get by a crowd, you say this along with *excuse me*, *pardon me*.
> *Excuse me*, I'm tryin to get through here - **Hot soup. Hot soup**.

No, you don't need to be carrying warm food, heavy pots, or watch-your-lap liquids.

Also, [**Pull Rank**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%20rank):

> Use a high position to get special treatment.